# Differentiate between base and derived class when passing as parameters to overloaded methods

Tags: c#, visitor-pattern

I'm currently implementing the visitor pattern in C# for a lecture in the university. It works fine at the moment, but I have a question for a task we had to do.
At the moment I have something like this:

```
public class TreeStructure<T>
{
  protected TreeStructure<T> _left;
  protected TreeStructure<T> _right;
  public T myValue;

  public TreeStructure(TreeStructure<T> left, T value ,TreeStructure<T> right)
  {
    this._left = left;
    this._right = right; 
    this.myValue = value;
  }
  public virtual void InOrder(MyVisitor<T> visitor)
  {
    if(!IsEmpty(this._left))
    {
      _left.InOrder(visitor);
    }
    visitor.Visit(this);
    if(!IsEmpty(this._right))
    {
      _right.InOrder(visitor);
    }
  }
  protected bool IsEmpty(TreeStructure<T> node)
  {
    return node == null;
  }
}

 public class SpecialTree<T> : TreeStructure<T>
  {
    public SpecialTree(TreeStructure<T> left, T value, TreeStructure<T> right)
    {
      this._left = left;
      this._right = right;
      this.myValue = value;
    }

    public override void InOrder(MyVisitor<T> visitor)
    {
      if(!IsEmpty(this._left))
      {
        _left.InOrder(visitor);
      }
      visitor.Visit(this);
      Console.WriteLine("Hallo");
      if(!IsEmpty(this._right))
      {
        _right.InOrder(visitor);
      }
    }
  }
```

And now we should implement some visitors. It was no problem, until we should differentiate in one visitor the type of the tree. So I have now one visitor looking like this:

```
  public interface MyVisitor<T>
  {
    void Visit(TreeStructure<T> tree);
  }

  public class CountVisitor<T> : MyVisitor<T>
  {
    public int count { get; set;}
    public CountVisitor()
    {
      count = 0;
    }

    public void Visit(TreeStructure<T> tree)
    {
      count++;
    }

    public void Visit(SpecialTree<T> specialTree)
    {
      count+=2;
    }
  }
```

So the question or the problem I have is, that this apparently works in Java, but not in C#. The `Visit()` Method for `SpecialTree`is never called. So I know that I can check specifically for the type of the object like here: [What is the best way to differentiate between derived classes of a base class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1349961/what-is-the-best-way-to-differentiate-between-derived-classes-of-a-base-class)
But can someone explain to me, why it doesn't work with overloaded methods? Or do I have a mistake here?

EDIT: Here is one test initialisation of a tree:

```
TreeStructure<int> tree1 = new TreeStructure<int>(new TreeStructure<int>  (null,3,null),1,new SpecialTree<int>(null,2,null));
      CountVisitor<int> visitor2 = new CountVisitor<int>();
      tree1.InOrder(visitor2);
      Console.WriteLine("Nodecount: " + visitor2.count.ToString());
```

Comment: What's `MyVisitor<T>`?

Comment: A short but complete example demonstrating the problem (and ideally nothing else - it needn't use trees or visitors at all) would really help. I strongly *suspect* that the equivalent code in Java wouldn't work either, but we really need to see a complete example in order to tell...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot, it's just a selfmade interface. I will add it to the start post.

Comment: @RolandM Side note: the convention in C# is that interfaces should start with `I` so that would be `IMyVistor<T>` :)

Comment: Ok. I didn't want to call it IVisitor because of possible conflicts with already implemented interfaces, but ok, I will remember it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is highly dependant on the implementation of `MyVisitor<T>`. In your comment you say it is an interface. Are you sure this is the whole example? The code you show in your question does not compile because the `SpecialTree<T>` does not invoke its parent constructor.

If `MyVisitor<T>` does not declare `Visit(SpecialTree<T> specialTree)`, the interface dispatch done by `InOrder` will never reach the `SpecialTree` case.

**Update**

Considering your updated initialization code, and assuming the interface is declared as this:

```
interface MyVisitor<T>
{
    void Visit(TreeStructure<T> treeStructure);
    void Visit(SpecialTree<T> tree);
}
```

Your `CountVisitor<T>` gives me a result of 4, as expected.

**Why didn't it work?**

I'll try to explain why your example did not work. The method `InOrder` in the class `SpecialTree` has a parameter of type `MyVisitor`. When the method `Visit` is called on `MyVisitor`, there is no overload that takes `SpecialTree`, however, there is an overload that takes `TreeStructure`. C# does not consider the implementation of the interface when looking for the correct method to call. Therefore, the method that has `TreeStructure` as a parameter is invoked instead of the method that accepts the `SpecialTree` parameter.

**What if I don't care what kind of tree structure it is?**

In response to your comment, you can just create a method that will be called by all implementations of the tree:

```
class DoNotCareVisitor<T> : MyVisitor<T> {
    void GenericVisit(TreeStructure<T> tree) {  
        //.. do whatever 
    }
    public void Visit(TreeStructure<T> tree) {
        GenericVisit(tree);
    }
    public void Visit(SpecialTree<T> tree) {
        GenericVisit(treeStructure);
    }
}
```

Comment: the OP has updated his code with the interface declaration and you are right that it only has one overload on it so updating it to your example would work (I think).

Comment: But then I habe a problem with visitors that doesn't need to differentiate between base and derived class!?

Comment: Ok, I understand the problem now. But I have several visitors, and not all of them need to differentiate between the base an the derived class. When I change now the interface, I need to implement this methods also for all visitors, right?

Comment: @RolandM - No, it's not correct. The point of the visitor class is that it doesn't need to change. You override the `InOrder` method for any derived classes that need to treat the visitor differently.

Comment: @RolandM - From Wikipedia "the visitor design pattern is a way of separating an algorithm from an object structure on which it operates". If you have to modify the visitor based on changes to your object structure then you are not using the visitor pattern.

Comment: But then I would have to differentiate in the visited object which visitor I call. Like in this example: When I have a visitor, that increments the value of the node, I don't want to call it twice.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `Visit(SpecialTree<T> specialTree)` is not a part of your `MyVisitor<T>` interface (btw - it is a good practice to prefix your interfaces with a capital `I`, so `IMyVisitor<T>` would improve readability), so there's no reason why it would be called.

In other words, when you're calling `visitor.Visit(this)`, your visitor variable is of type `MyVisitor<T>`, so at this point the compiler is not aware that you intend to use a specific class there, which incidentally might have a better overload of your function.

The easiest way - assuming you're not purposefully trying to write it like this (and to make it work, you'd need to employ runtime type checking) - would be to add a second method to your interface, with the following signature: `void Visit(SpecialTree<T> specialTree)`.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is check the distinction between the trees in `public void Visit(TreeStructure<T> tree)`, like this:

```
public class CountVisitor<T> : MyVisitor<T>
{
    public int count { get; set;}
    public CountVisitor()
    {
      count = 0;
    }

    public void Visit(TreeStructure<T> tree)
    {
      if (tree is SpecialTree<T>)
          count += 2;
      else
          count++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to differentiate between the two tree types. The purpose of the visitor is to traverse the structure and collect some sort of metric in a general way.

The visitor should look like this:

```
public class CountVisitor<T> : MyVisitor<T>
{
    public int count { get; set;}

    public CountVisitor()
    {
        count = 0;
    }

    public void Visit(TreeStructure<T> tree)
    {
        count++;
    }
}
```

That's it.

Here's what you need to do in your `SpecialTree<T>` class:

```
public override void InOrder(MyVisitor<T> visitor)
{
    if(!IsEmpty(this._left))
    {
        _left.InOrder(visitor);
    }
    visitor.Visit(this);
    visitor.Visit(this);
    if(!IsEmpty(this._right))
    {
        _right.InOrder(visitor);
    }
}
```

So basically, it's the purpose of the override in the `SpecialTree<T>` class to call the `.Visit` method twice.

Now when I run your test code I get:

```
Nodecount: 4
```

Comment: Isn't it like this, that the visited object doesn't care about its own type and that the visitor should check? Or is it this way, that the visitor shouldn't care?

Comment: @RolandM - The point of using a visitor is that it is separated from the object structures that it traverses. So the sole purpose of the `CountVisitor` class is to count the nodes. It doesn't need to know that `SpecialTree` has a special property that each node has a count of two. If tomorrow you decide that each node in a `SpecialTree` is worth a count of three then you should not need to change the `CountVisitor` - you just add an extra call to the visitor in `InOrder`. That's where it belongs.